# Which flag needs to be set in OpenCV 2.4.3.1 installed by apt-get under Ubuntu 16.04 to get imread?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, makefile

I have installed OpenCV with the command `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`. Now I want to write a simple code to read in an image file,

Basically it looks like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main(void){

        cv::Mat image;
        image = cv::imread("test.png");
}
```

I put the following line to the Makefile

```
LIBRARIES :=  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc
```

I read that in Opencv > 3 one has to add the `-lopencv_imgcodec`, however I am on version 2.4, and when I try this flag it gets not found.

My current error states the following:

```
 undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)
```

I also tried with the `pkg-config --cflags opencv` option as libs, however then I get the commonly known libtiff4.0 error under Linux.

Comment: It would help if you post the "commonly known" libtiff4.0 error under Linux. Have you tried passing "pkg-config --libs opencv"?

Comment: Yes that is when the libtiff error occurs, which is sth known under Linux, and not the focus of the problem, since this only comes when one tries to include highgui, I can live without that. The focus is still on the -lopencv_imgcodec

Comment: `imread` is from the [`highgui` module](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)